# Is this an appropriate use for shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, linux

Project: typical chat program.  Server must receive text from multiple clients and fan each input out to all clients.

In the server I want to have each client to have a struct containing the socket fd and a std::queue.  Each structure will be on a std::list.

As input is received from a client socket I want to iterate over the list of structs and put new input into each client struct's queue.  A string is new[ed] because I don't want copies of the string multiplied over all the clients.  But I also want to avoid the headache of have multiple pointers to the string spread out and deciding when it is time to finally delete the string.

Is this an appropriate occassion for a shared pointer?  If so, is the shared_ptr incremented each time I push them into the queue and decremented when I pop them from the queue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, though I think it's not an appropriate use of `std::list`. `vector` FTW! :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal - why a vector?  OP's choice of list seems better for something where connections are continually added and deleted.

Comment: @Duck: `std::list` has poor locality, which commonly hurts performance more than a few extra copies.

Comment: If you're using TCP, be aware that `send()`/`write()` may, when pointed at a buffer of N characters, successfully send anywhere from 1 to N.  It is up to your app to resend any unsent characters from that buffer later.  So, you shouldn't just track strings to be sent; you need the next index within the "current" string.  Alternatively, an index into a single string, rope (if your implementation(s) provides and further portability's not essential), deque<char> or circular buffer to which you append text... all with different performance/convenience compromises.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: I would recommend trying to send the whole string and if you get a partial send, just push a new string (to the *front* of the queue) with the leftover.

Comment: @David: guess you disagree with "all with different performance/convenience compromises" is you're recommending something without discussing the trade-offs...?  An `erase` operation on the partially sent string while on the queue would be better than a pop/new-string/push.  From a TCP perspective, it's optimal to aim to write as much as possible in each `send()` or `write()`, rather than doing sends on each string independently, though modern BSD/POSIX compliant systems will have `writev()`....

Comment: I didn't say to do sends on each string independently! I said to try to send the whole string as opposed to part of it. You can certainly assemble the strings into a send buffer and save the leftover from that send buffer. I'm saying to move strings into the send buffer as whole strings and save the leftover from the send buffer. (And "I would recommend" implies that it's my judgment that this generally makes the best trade offs for the suggested application.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where a pseudo-garbage collector system will work much better than reference counting.

You need only one list of strings, because you "fan every input out to all clients".  Because you will add to one end and remove from the other, a `deque` is an appropriate data structure.

Now, each connection needs only to keep track of the index of the last string it sent.  Periodically (every 1000th message received, or every 4MB received, or something like that), you find the minimum of this index across all clients, and delete strings up to that point.  This periodic check is also an opportunity to detect clients which have fallen far behind (possible broken connection) and recover.  Without this check, a single stuck client will cause your program to leak memory (even under the reference counting scheme).

This scheme is several times less data than reference counting, and also removes one of the major points of cache contention (reference counts must be written from multiple threads, so they ruin performance).  If you aren't using threads, it'll still be faster.

Comment: An interesting way to think about it.  It touches on an upcoming concern of how to handle slow clients.  I will have to think on this.  Thank you.

Comment: And if you need to send messages to one client specifically occasionally, you can just keep them on a separate queue.

Answer (score 2):

That is an appropriate use of a `shared_ptr`. And yes, the use count will be increment because a new `shared_ptr` will be create to push.

Comment: To be clear if I do: rawPtr = new string; shared_ptr(raw); push(shared_ptr);...is the refcnt 1 or 2 at that point?  If 2, then it really gets deleted after whatever pops it then goes out of scope, correct?  Pls overlook syntax of above, i am just seeking the concept.

Comment: If you push the same `shared_ptr` more than once and then it goes out of scope, the count will be the number of pushes. (Be sure to push copies of the *same* `shared_ptr`.)